# non visibile panel not updating with dropdownlist change

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="userNameDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="PK_User" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [PK_User] FROM [User] ORDER BY [Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And a page with multiple panels. On the first panel, this menu effects how information is inputted into a database. On the second panel it affects how the data is shown:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4"
            AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None"
            BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_OnRowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_OnRowEditing" 
            DataKeyNames="PK_DailyTaskHours, PK_NonScrumStory" AutoPostBack="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Catagory" HeaderText="Support Catagory" SortExpression="Catagory" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AppName" HeaderText="Application Name" SortExpression="IncidentNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="IncidentNumber" HeaderText="Incident #" SortExpression="IncidentNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Hours" HeaderText="Hours" SortExpression="Hours" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedDate" HeaderText="Created Date" SortExpression="CreatedDate"  />
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [NonScrumStory].[IncidentNumber], [NonScrumStory].[Description], [NonScrumStory].[CreatedDate], 
            [DailyTaskHours].[Hours], [Application].[AppName], [SupportCatagory].[Catagory], [DailyTaskHours].[PK_DailyTaskHours], 
            [NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] FROM [NonScrumStory], [DailyTaskHours], [Application], [SupportCatagory] WHERE 
            ([NonScrumStory].[UserId] = @userIdSelected) AND ([NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] = [DailyTaskHours].[NonScrumStoryId]) 
            AND ([NonScrumStory].[CatagoryId] = [SupportCatagory].[PK_SupportCatagory]) AND 
            ([NonScrumStory].[ApplicationId] = [Application].[PK_Application]) AND ([NonScrumStory].[Deleted] != 1)"
            DeleteCommand="UPDATE [NonScrumStory] SET [Deleted] = 1 WHERE (PK_NonScrumStory = @nonScrumStoryPK); 
            UPDATE [DailyTaskHours] SET [Deleted] = 1 WHERE (PK_DailyTaskHours = @dailyTaskHoursPK); ">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userIdSelected" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="dailyTaskHoursPK" Type="String" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="nonScrumStoryPK" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is the code on the back end of the page to make the change:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //change WHERE clause for SQL statement that effects grid view based on drop down menu selection
    SqlDataSource4.SelectParameters["userIdSelected"].DefaultValue = userNameDropDown.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

There are radio buttons that show and hide the panels. When the panel that shows the gridview is open, the change in the drop down menu is reflected and the gridview updates.

When the other radio button is selected and the gridview panel is hidden and the user changes the drop down menu, the update is not reflected. You you change the radio button again and show the gridview panel, the previous table is being shown. How do I fix this?

Comment: if you are using the same grid ... are you rebinding to show the new data?

Comment: That was it, Ill have to research binding more.

Comment: Something else that might help is that you can bind the sqlparam to the drop down.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter(v=vs.100).aspx